# Animate application icon in windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, animation, icons

I have tried googling for this and came up empty. What I want is a tutorial or example code of how to change my icon on the windows phone like the people application or SMS. For example when you get a new SMS message it puts a number next to the face in the icon. Is there any way for me to do that in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send a [Tile Push Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

This allows you to update the image, text and (optionally) a number.

Push notifications shoudl be triggered from a remote [web] service.

You can also have the tile update periodically using a [ShellTileSchedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can update your application's Tile using Push Notifications from a web service registered with a Microsoft Push Notification Service. However, this isn't absolutely necessary. You can even update your tiles without push notifications, by setting a ShellTileSchedule. The minimum update interval is 1 hour, however.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).